# $\gcd(I,J)\cdot \mathrm{lcm}(I,J)=(I+J)(I\cap J)=IJ$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to understand the following statement given in Mollin's Algebraic Number Theory: $\gcd(I,J)\cdot \mathrm{lcm}(I,J)=(I+J)(I\cap J)=IJ$

The inclusion $(I\cap J)(I+J)\subseteq IJ$ is clear.

For the other inclusion, the author states "Conversely, any element in $IJ $ is in both $I$ and $J$, so in $I\cap J$, and trivially $I+J$. Thus $IJ\subseteq (I\cap J)(I+J)$."

I am confused by his reasoning. I understand that an element of $IJ$ is in $I\cap J$ and $I+J$, however I'm not sure why this implies it's in their product $(I\cap J)(I+J)$.

What am I missing?

Comment: That justification is bull. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738670/the-relation-between-the-product-of-two-ideals-and-the-intersection-of-these-two for a correct proof.